# can collection select batch size be defined SessionFactory-wide in Hibernate 4?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate's `@BatchSize` can be used to define select batch size behavior for annotated collections (or types). However, is there a way to configure `SessionFactory` to set a global select batch size for all collections - instead of having to annotate one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can specify `hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size` while configuring session factory to set default batch size.

refer to link for [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-lazy)